# REST query works on one site but not another

Tags: 2013, rest, enterprise-search, query

I have an query

> "< my_url >/fr/_api/search/query?querytext=..."

It works fine and returns what I want. However when I try

> "< my_url >/en/_api/search/query?querytext=..."

This fails with an 500 error.

What could cause a working query to fail on another site?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution

in fr: it is 100,00

in en: it is 100.00